# Error parsing XML feed from my wordpress blog using php curl

Tags: php, curl, xml-parsing, rss

https://blog.onlywire.com/category/content-submission/feed/

This is my feed URL. For some reason, I am not able to parse it using PHP. What am I missing?

The script:

```
$ch = curl_init( $feed_curl );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: no error. it works for other feeds..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to see if you're getting any curl error - and don't forget to close the handler!

```
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // return into a variable
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $result = curl_exec($ch); // run!
        if($result === FALSE) {
            var_dump(curl_error($ch));
        }
        else {
            var_dump($result);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: +1 for `curl_error()`.  Also, adding this shows that it can't validate the cert [`Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates`].  So changing `https://` to `http://` fixes that and you're feed contents is returned as expected.

Comment: I tried changing the link to http.. but no luck.. i have curl enabled on my server. also i tried putting curl_error().. it gives nothing.. can anyone of u check if it works on your server?. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Samarth, your original code worked for me having just changed `https` to `http`.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a file of root CAs:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/your/cafile');
```

You can download a CA file from the curl website:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html